# Is there any way for users with less than 10,000 rep to see a comments connected to a deleted question after it’s been deleted?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

So there have been a few times I have left a comment on a question, got a response to that comment that lands in my inbox and I get an alert. All good and normal, right? But then I click my inbox alert I go to that question, it’s deleted and since I don’t have 10,000+ rep on that particular Stack Exchange site, I cannot read the comment connected to that deleted question.

Is there some way a user with less than 10,000 rep can read a comment directed at them that is connected to a deleted question? Or is the general consensus that most comments are disposable and in the case of a deleted question the comment is probably just too chatty to care about? Is this a feature, bug or a “Ehh… It seems like something but that not that big of a something…”

There have been a few times the responses seemed indignant and ignorable so hey… Happy to not read the rest! But on a few occasions it seems like the comment was something along the lines of “Thanks for the comment! That was helpful! I will be doing something like this…” and of course that’s all I can read since the question is gone and so are the associated comments.

Sometimes it would be nice to read what’s there since the impression from the sender might be I have been able to read the full comment when in reality I can’t since it’s gone from my POV.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such way and I don't think there should be.

Users with less than 10K rep can't see deleted questions or answers (unless their own), and as a result can't see comments on such deleted questions or answers. And that is it.

Just because you got notification about it should not give you powers you don't usually have.